# Java GUI - Display JTextField Value

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel, jtextfield

Link to code [pastiebin](https://www.pastiebin.com/59499211138e4)

I have a JTextField on my first GUI window. Later in the program I open another GUI and go to display the value of the JTextField but in the program I get an error of invalid layout. I'm not sure what I need to change to get it to display the correct value.

Picture for reference

[image]

Comment: Please post **all** code here with your question, not as code formatted text. Please show a link to an image not to an HTML page that holds the image.

Comment: links description added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JLabel supfirst = new JLabel("Supervisors First Name :" + firstvalue.getText());
```

**.getText()** is probably what you're missing.

This is what displays the content from the input field.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!